# Destroy session in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, logout

I am new to `JSP`. I have created set of pages in web application using login system.

I want to do log out option, and it should be appeared on every page.

Please I need the full source code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the session object in JSP to expire the session.

```
session.invalidate();
```

**UPDATE**

Make a separate header page and show sign out option when the user has signed on. After clicking on the sign out then do as I told you.

After destroying the session then redirect the user to home page.

```
response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
```